# How to use parameterized stored procedure for report viewer WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, report

I am working on report viewer in WPF.

I have dynamic sql query which generate on server side.Then i pass this query to stored procedure and execute and return the result.

**Problem :**

I want to consume this stored procedure for generating reports.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot on web but all solutions for stored procedures which consume static query.To solve this problem i used following steps :-

1.)Make static query in stored procedure.

2.)Use stored procedure for Dataset.

3.)bind this dataset with .rdlc file.

4.)Buil project.

5.)Change the stored procedure to previous one.

6.)now refresh the dataset.

You get the working report now :-)